# securing and encrypting .mdb file in c#

Tags: c#

I want to make my MS Access file (.mdb) unreadable/readable based on a key, using C#. I want to do this without using any third party tools.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to simply encrypt one file with a C# application? .Net has encryption functions built in that you could do that with. You could read all of the bytes in and encrypt it that way. Should be simple enough but wanted to make sure this is what you're trying to do.

Comment: by doing this can i give a key to my file which no body will be able to read my .mdb file???
and it will be secure!!

Comment: please guide me how to use that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you are using MS Access data file? If you have the flexibility you might consider using Sqlite which has a very nice .NET wrapper and support for entity framework if you like, basically you end up with only one dll and the database file. Best of all Sqlite supports basic database encryption. http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: i think if use this, i will be encrypt this as well so i cant do this because it is a database file, but i can encrypt a text file or stream, so thanks a lot give a solution on my own db .mdb file thankssss

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dh224hh.aspx

This uses DESEncryption, and you should setup the IV (initialisation vector) to anything you want, as long as it's always the same, and the key (your password) can only be 8 bytes long.

To convert a string to bytes, you can use

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bkey = ue.GetBytes(key);
```

I'll leave it up to you to make that 8 bytes long.

You may also want to store somewhere (e.g. another file) whether or not the mdb file is currently encrypted, because you don't want to end up encrypting it multiple times... in which case it could be quite hard to get it back.

Comment: i know and i can encrypt text a text file but i cant my .mdb file so how plz tell me with some details if it is possible in show me with a simple example. thanks alot